# Count and position a column python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, count

Using python3, I am working with a DataFrame with 2 columns, the first column is made of dates: for example from 2017-12-18 to 2017-12-25 (but it can change based on the user input). And the relative data on the second column.

What I need is to add a third column in the first position of the DataFrame as such:

```
1;2017-12-18;Data1
2;2017-12-19;Data2

n;last_date;DataN

import numpy as np
def func(df):
    count = np.count_nonzero(df['Data_column'])
    l = np.array([x for x in range(count)])
    df['day_count'][0] = l
    return l
```

But it keeps giving me wrong results, what I am mistaking?
Thanks in advance!

P.s. I used the count_nonzero because sometimes I could have N/A or blank values in the time series.

Comment: Can you explain (in simple language) what your first column is meant to represent? 2 rows of data with `1, 2` can have a large number of interpretations.

Comment: it represents the number of days, so that I can do operations later on